# Aframe Doesn't Render WebVR on Mobile?

Tags: ios, aframe, progressive-web-apps, virtual-reality, webvr

I have a Progressive Web App that is using aframe to render a vr image.

Here is my aframe markup:

```
<a-scene>
   <a-sky src="images/vr-assets/test1.jpg"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Very simple. And it works fine in Firefox.

However, when testing on iOS, I get prompted to put my phone in a headset.

I want to use WebVR regardless of the environment so that my users don't have to use a headset. So my scene should not care about the device the user is using and should display like it does on desktop.

After looking at the docs, I tried passing in `isMobile="false"` like so:

```
<a-scene isMobile="false">
    <a-sky src="images/vr-assets/test1.jpg"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

But this didn't change anything.

Furthermore, passing in `isMobile="false"` breaks the code.

I get these warning messages in Firefox:

```
TypeError: s.requestPresent is not a function

TypeError: can't assign to property "depthNear" on 0: not an object
```

Does anyone know a way of forcing aframe to only render using WebVR?

Comment: A-Frame should work out of the box as you describe. No need of aditional flags. See [A-Frame examples](https://aframe.io/examples/). Default mode is magic window that rotates the camera using the phone sensors, no headset required. The enter VR button triggers stereo view that needs a cardboard type holder and hence the message you saw displayed. Are your expectations different?

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Thanks for the reply. When I run my app, the scene doesn't display automatically. I see a blank screen with the enter VR button on the side. So maybe I am loading the scene incorrectly (dynamically with React) and that is causing the issue. I will investigate